# Equivalent of python's ord(), chr() in go?

Tags: go

What is the equivalent of python's [chr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) and [ord()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) functions in golang?

```
chr(97) = 'a'
ord('a') = 97
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They are supported as simple [conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
ch := rune(97)
n := int('a')
fmt.Printf("char: %c\n", ch)
fmt.Printf("code: %d\n", n)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/FMqjMMRW0z)):

```
char: a
code: 97
```

Note: you can also convert an [integer numeric value to a `string`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type) which basically interprets the integer value as the UTF-8 encoded value:

```
s := string(97)
fmt.Printf("text: %s\n", s) // Output: text: a
```

> Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer. Values outside the range of valid Unicode code points are converted to `"\uFFFD"`.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that a simple `uint8('a')` will produce a correct output. To convert from integer to string `string(98)` will suffice:

```
uint8('g') // 103
string(112) // p
```