# Char to Ascii int conversion in Go Language

Tags: c#, .net, go

we have a project migration happening from C# .Net to Go language. I have completed most part of it but i am stuck at one place. In c#, i have a code,

```
(int)char < 31
```

How can i write this in Go language?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found answer my self with below change

```
var r rune
r = 'a' // char
r < 31
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

There is no "char" type in Go, the closest you can get is `rune` which is an alias for `int32`.

Being an alias of `int32` means the types `int32` and `rune` are identical and you can treat a `rune` like an `int32` number (so you can compare it, add to it / subtract from it etc.).

But know that Go is strict about types, and you can't compare values of different types (in your answer you are comparing it with an untyped integer constant which is ok). For example the following code is a compile-time error:

```
var r rune = 'a'
var i int = 100
if r < i { // Compile-time error: invalid operation: r < i (mismatched types rune and int)
    fmt.Println("less")
}
```

Should you need to convert a value of `rune` or any other integer type to another integer type (e.g. `rune` to `int`), you can use simple type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), e.g..

```
var r rune = 'a'
var i int = 100
if int(r) < i {
    fmt.Println("less")
}
```

See related question: [Equivalent of python's ord(), chr() in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914662/equivalent-of-pythons-ord-chr-in-go)