# How to convert ascii code to byte in golang?

Tags: go

As the title say, I can find the function to give me ascii code of bytes, but not the other way around

Comment: ASCII is 7 bit and fits very well into a byte. Please clarify.

Comment: I just started to learn go - what I wanted is to generate latin alphabet using `for` loop, and parsing int values to chars. Sorry if I asked the wrong question

Comment: `for c := 'A'; c <='Z'; c++ { fmt.Printf("%c", c) }`. Int-values _are_ chars, maybe you want to convert them to runes. Please study "Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go" https://blog.golang.org/strings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of python's ord(), chr() in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914662/equivalent-of-pythons-ord-chr-in-go/29914705#29914705)

Answer (score 7):

Golang string literals are UTF-8 and since ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, and each of its characters are only 7 bits, we can easily get them as bytes by casting (e.g. `bytes := []byte(str)`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  asciiStr := "ABC"
  asciiBytes := []byte(asciiStr)

  fmt.Printf("OK: string=%v, bytes=%v\n", asciiStr, asciiBytes)
  fmt.Printf("OK: byte(A)=%v\n", asciiBytes[0])
}
// OK: string=ABC, bytes=[65 66 67]
// OK: byte(A)=65
```