# Char '0' not equal to int 0?

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"
func  main() {
   fmt.Println(byte('0'))

}
```

why run this code On Mac which print **48**, not **0** ? 
in c char '0' always equal to number 0, please explain this to me, or I'm totally wrong !

Comment: `byte` returns the ASCII value of the character. If your case, it's 48.

Comment: The byte value of `'0'` is 48 (decimal). You the value `0` isn't printable as a visible character. In C, the character `'0'` is *not* equal to the number 0. It's 48 in C as well. It's unclear why you believe otherwise.

Comment: As lurker mentioned: this is expected in both languages. Try the following in C: `printf("char: %c, int: %d\n", '0', '0');`. The first is printing the character representation (`'0'`), the second is printing its integer value (`48`).

Comment: @lurker yeah, I read the ascii table again, '0' equal to 48 !! thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is how the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package works. [`fmt.Println()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) will use the *default* format for its arguments, which is `%d` for integer values (such as `byte`, `int` etc., and even for `rune`) which means to print its numerical base 10 representation. `'0'` is a [rune literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals), when passed to `fmt.Println()` it will take the type `rune` which is an alias for `int32`, so it's an integer value, it has decimal value `48`.

```
fmt.Println('0', rune('0'), byte('0'))
```

This prints:

```
48 48 48
```

If you want to print the character, convert it to `string`, or use a format string with `%c` verb:

```
fmt.Println(string('0'))
fmt.Printf("%c", '0')
```

This prints:

```
0
0
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CX79GPOIwAl).

See related: [Equivalent of python's ord(), chr() in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914662/equivalent-of-pythons-ord-chr-in-go)

Answer (score 1):

> in c char '0' always equal to number 0, please explain this to me, or I'm totally wrong !

You're totally wrong :P . Here's the C equivalent of your code.

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("%d\n",'0');
}

$ gcc -o tc t.c && ./tc
48
```

However, if you specifically *tell* `printf` to interpret '0' as a character, you'll get  a literal `0`, - its binary representation is decimal 48.

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("%d %c %c\n", '0', '0', 48);
}

$ gcc -o tc t.c && ./tc
48 0 0
```